# How to extend the Owin OAuth to accommodate the Application level login confirmation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, owin

I am currently working with MVC5 application which is using Owin OAuth authentication. I am looking forward to extend the login criteria where I have added couple of tables (Application table (ApplicationId(guid), ApplicationName(nvarchar) and ApplicationUserTable(id, ApplicationId(FK from Application table), UserId(FK column from ASPNetUsers table))) in my security DB.
Could please anyone give me some idea on how to access this ApplicationUserTable in Owin context so that I can verify first if user belong to a particular application? I have looked through quite a few examples but didn't find anything relevant to the particular scenario i am working with.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your ApplicationId field as the ClientId, then you will have a different ClientId for each application.

When the user sends an authentication token request, in the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method when you check the user credentials, check if the user belongs to the application that received ClientId represents.

In a simple way, it could be something like the following:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    ...
    var user = await _userService.GetUserAsync(context.UserName, context.Password, context.ClientId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name, password or clientId is incorrect.");
        return;
    }
    ...
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

And in the user service:

```
public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(string userName, string password, string clientId = null)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

    if (user == null || (clientId != null && user.ApplicationUsers.Where(au => au.ApplicationId == clientId).Count() == 0))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return user;
}
```

In the `ValidateClientAuthentication` method you should validate the ClientId-Secret are in your Application table.

I hope it helps.